# Allocation for rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables lets say #table1 and #table2. Table1 has 282 rows and for columns column1, column2, column3 and column4(modulo)key.
Table2 has two columns, column1, which has 8 rows containing agent1 to agent8, and modulo 1 to 8.

I need to allocate these 8 agents rows in table1, making sure count of column1 is equally distributed between agent1 to agent6, however as agent7 and agent8 are part-time, their allocation is 0.86 per and 0.80 of target values for column1, column2 and column3. I am using SQL to allocate these rows but my output is missing 10 rows, can't debug why.

Here is the closest script I have got, I can distribute them equally easily but its just when trying to put condition for each columns I am struggling to get correct output of 282 rows. My code is giving 270 rows output.

```
DECLARE @Agent7SCV DECIMAL(18, 3) = 32;
DECLARE @Agent7RenMeters DECIMAL(18, 3) = 49;
DECLARE @Agent7RenCons DECIMAL(18, 3) = 5983847;
DECLARE @Agent8SCV DECIMAL(18, 3) = 28;
DECLARE @Agent8RenMeters DECIMAL(18, 3) = 44;
DECLARE @Agent8RenCons DECIMAL(18, 3) = 5522480;

DECLARE @TotalSCV DECIMAL(18, 3) = 282;
DECLARE @TotalRenMeters DECIMAL(18, 3) = 435;
DECLARE @TotalRenCons DECIMAL(18, 3) = 52988473;
DECLARE @TotalRows INT = 8;

-- Calculate target SCVs for other agents
DECLARE @OtherAgentsSCV DECIMAL(18, 3);
SET @OtherAgentsSCV = @TotalSCV - (@Agent7SCV + @Agent8SCV);

-- Calculate target Ren Meters for other agents
DECLARE @OtherAgentsRenMeters DECIMAL(18, 3);
SET @OtherAgentsRenMeters = @TotalRenMeters - (@Agent7RenMeters + @Agent8RenMeters);

-- Calculate target Ren Cons for other agents
DECLARE @OtherAgentsRenCons DECIMAL(18, 3);
SET @OtherAgentsRenCons = @TotalRenCons - (@Agent7RenCons + @Agent8RenCons);

-- Calculate the required number of rows for each agent based on targets
WITH AgentAlloc AS (
    SELECT 
        Agents,
        CASE 
            WHEN Agents = 'Agent7' THEN @Agent7SCV
            WHEN Agents = 'Agent8' THEN @Agent8SCV
            ELSE @OtherAgentsSCV / (@TotalRows - 2) -- for other agents
        END AS TargetSCV,
        CASE 
            WHEN Agents = 'Agent7' THEN @Agent7RenMeters
            WHEN Agents = 'Agent8' THEN @Agent8RenMeters
            ELSE @OtherAgentsRenMeters / (@TotalRows - 2) -- for other agents
        END AS TargetRenMeters,
        CASE 
            WHEN Agents = 'Agent7' THEN @Agent7RenCons
            WHEN Agents = 'Agent8' THEN @Agent8RenCons
            ELSE @OtherAgentsRenCons / (@TotalRows - 2) -- for other agents
        END AS TargetRenCons,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        #table2
),
Allocation AS (
    SELECT 
        t1.SCV,
        t1.Ren_Meters,
        t1.Ren_Cons,
        aa.Agents,
        aa.TargetSCV,
        aa.TargetRenMeters,
        aa.TargetRenCons,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aa.Agents ORDER BY NEWID()) AS AgentRowNum,
        t1.Modulo
    FROM 
        #table1 t1
    JOIN 
        AgentAlloc aa ON t1.Modulo % @TotalRows = aa.RowNum - 1
)
SELECT *
FROM Allocation
WHERE 
    (
        (Agents = 'Agent7' AND AgentRowNum <= TargetSCV AND Ren_Meters <= TargetRenMeters AND Ren_Cons <= TargetRenCons) OR
        (Agents = 'Agent8' AND AgentRowNum <= TargetSCV AND Ren_Meters <= TargetRenMeters AND Ren_Cons <= TargetRenCons) OR
        (Agents != 'Agent7' AND Agents != 'Agent8' AND AgentRowNum <= TargetSCV AND Ren_Meters <= TargetRenMeters AND Ren_Cons <= TargetRenCons)
    )

ORDER BY Modulo, Agents, AgentRowNum;
```

Comment: I'm having a very difficult time understanding your problem description. Sample data, desired results, and current actual results would go a long ways towards helping us understand your problem. Please try to reduce reduce your problem down to the minimum required to demonstrate your problem - perhaps a dozen or two rows instead of 282. Also, please use meaningful table and column names, not Table1, Column1.

Comment: It would be best if you could create a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-) containing your table definitions, data inserts, and current query to give us something we can work with. Paste the resulting URL back to your question.